# Returning value from thread Java/ Android

Tags: java, android, java-threads

I have the following thread in my android class. How can I get the value of err from the thread???

```
public int method(){
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        int err;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            err = device.verify(30, 5, coderChoice, detectModeChoice,
                      0, listSearch, callbackCmd, MTFPSD.this, matchingScore);
            updateView("Finger Captured Successfully", err);

        }
    }).start();

return err;
}
```

I want the value to be the return value of the method but for the life of me I can't get the value...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two ways of achieving this.

1. The *bad* way.
   Create a mutable object like a *list* of integers and let the Thread (Runnable) write into the list. You can access the value in the list in the outer class / method.
2. Use a [`Callable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) instead of a `Runnable` . A `Callable` can return values

Comment: @Astora - In case of Android you could use a handler as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise, You can use `Handler` to catch `err` value.

```
public void method(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
            int err;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                err = device.verify(30, 5, coderChoice, detectModeChoice,
                          0, listSearch, callbackCmd, MTFPSD.this, matchingScore);
                updateView("Finger Captured Successfully", err);

                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(err);

            }
        }).start();

    return;
    }

Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        int err = msg.what;

        // something to do.

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do when my Runnable and Handler are in different classes ^_^

```
public void task(final Handler h){


        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Do something...

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("Value", "Done");
                Message toDeliver = new Message();
                toDeliver.setData(bundle);
                h.sendMessage(toDeliver);

            }
        };

        Thread thread = new Thread(r);
        thread.start();

    }



Handler h = new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
                String result = bundle.getString("Value");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
```